# How to fix the mysql query from getting error

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error while running the mysql query.

```
INSERT INTO raw_table_200(entity_id, master_attribute_id, attribute_value, history_schedule_id, parent_id)
VALUES
((SELECT entity_id FROM raw_table_200 WHERE master_attribute_id = 37),38,(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(attribute_value,' ',-1) FROM raw_table_200 WHERE master_attribute_id=29),223,(SELECT raw_id FROM raw_table_200 WHERE master_attribute_id=31));
```

=========================================================

error thorws by mysql server is following

```
"You can't specify target table 'raw_table_200' for update in FROM clause"
```

Comment: A better question would explain what you are trying to do - as is the question will attract answers which may fix the immediate problem but may not be appropriate to what you are attempting to achieve. BTW your code looks really clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't select and insert in the same table then try force the building of a temo table this way

```
INSERT INTO raw_table_200 (entity_id, master_attribute_id, attribute_value, history_schedule_id, parent_id)
select * from (
    ((SELECT entity_id 
        FROM raw_table_200 WHERE master_attribute_id = 37)
        ,38
        , (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(attribute_value,' ',-1) 
        FROM raw_table_200 WHERE master_attribute_id=29)
        ,223
        , (SELECT raw_id FROM raw_table_200 WHERE master_attribute_id=31));
)  T
```